# How to apply formula in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to apply the formula in the column but not able to.

I have data in dataframe:

```
Date                  2018-04-16 00:00:00
Quantity                         8317.000
Total Value (Lacs)              259962.50
```

I want to apply a formula in `Total Value (Lacs)` column

formula is: `= [ Total Value (Lacs) multiplied by 100000 ] divided by [Quantity (000’s) multiplied by 100]` by using pandas

I have tried something

```
a = df['Total Value (Lacs)']
b = df['Quantity']

c = (a * 100000 / b * 100)
print (c)

or 

df['Price'] = ((df['Total Value (Lacs)']) * 100000 / (df['Quantity']) * 100)
print (df)
```

error:

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'str' and 'str'

**Edit**

I have tried below code:

```
df['Price'] = float((float(df['Total Value (Lacs)'])) * 100000 / float((df['Quantity'])) * 100)
```

but getting the wrong value

```
price     312567632.6
```

expecting

```
price     31256.76326
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit 1**
Type error means that you've tried to apply operator `/` to two strings. There's no such operator defined for `str` type in python, so you should convert you data to some numeric type, `float` in your case.

I didn't understand exactly how your data looks like. But if it's like this:

```
df
Out:
Date                   Quantity    Total Value (Lacs) 
2018-04-16 00:00:00    8317.000             259962.50  
2018-04-17 00:00:00    7823.000             234004.50
```

You can convert it to numeric type, convert all the columns to the correct type (I suppose that `Date` column is an index column):

```
df_float = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df_float.dtypes()
Out: 
Quantity              float64
Total Value (Lacs)      int64
dtype: object
```

After all, you can just deal with columns:

```
df['Price'] =  (df_float['Total Value (Lacs)'] * 100000 
                / df_float['Quantity'] * 100)
df['Price']
Out: 
2018-04-16 00:00:00    319930.7592441217
2018-04-17 00:00:00    334309.8102814262
```

Another approach is define the function and apply it to each row with `pd.DataFrame.apply`:

```
def get_price(row):
    try:
        price = (float(row['Total Value (Lacs)']) * 100000 
                 / float(row['Quantity']) * 100)
    except (TypeError, ValueError):  # If bad data in this row, can't convert to float
        price = None
    return price
        
df['Price'] =  df.apply(get_price, axis=1)
df['Price']
Out: 
2018-04-16 00:00:00    319930.7592441217
2018-04-17 00:00:00    334309.8102814262
```

`axis=1` means "apply to each row"

If you have transposed data - as in your example, you should transpose it or to apply function to each column using `axis=0`.

**Edit 2**:
Looks like your data is just single column, and it has dtype `pd.Series`. So if you select a row with `data['Quantity']`, you'll get something like `8317.000` of type `str`. There's no `pd.Series.apply` method, of course. So, in that case you may act in this way:

```
index_to_convert = ['Quantity', 'Total Value (Lacs)']
data[index_to_convert] = pd.to_numeric(data[index_to_convert])
```

- and only numeric columns were converted. The just do the formula:

  data['Price'] = (data['Total Value (Lacs)'] * 100000
  / data['Quantity'] * 100)
  data
  Out:
  Date                  2018-04-16 00:00:00
  Quantity                             8317
  Total Value (Lacs)                 259962
  Price                         3.12568e+08

But in most cases this solution not so handy, I strongly advice convert your data to `DataFrame` and deal with it, because `DataFrame` provides more flexibility and capabilities.
Сonverting process:

```
df = data.to_frame().T.set_index('Date')
```

There are three consecutive actions:

1. Convert your data into `DataFrame`
2. Transpose it to (now columns are vertical virtually)
3. Set `"Date"` as index column

Results:

```
df 
Out: 
                    Quantity Total Value (Lacs)
Date                                           
2018-04-16 00:00:00  8317.00          259962.50
```

After the previous steps you can apply **Edit 1** code to your data. Also it's applicable there is more than one series in your data.

**One more:**
If your data has more than one value for each index, i.e multiple quantities, etc:

```
data
Out: 
Date                  2018-04-16 00:00:00
Quantity                          8317.00
Total Value (Lacs)              259962.50
Date                  2018-04-17 00:00:00
Quantity                          6434.00
Total Value (Lacs)              230002.50
```

You also can convert it into `pd.DataFrame`, step-by-step.
Group your data by an index entries and apply a `list` to groups:

```
data.groupby(level=0).apply(list)
Out: 
Date                  [2018-04-16 00:00:00, 2018-04-17 00:00:00]
Quantity                                      [8317.00, 6434.00]
Total Value (Lacs)                        [259962.50, 230002.50]
```

Then apply `pd.Series` to each row:

```
data.groupby(level=0).apply(list).apply(pd.Series)
Out:                                  0                    1
Date                2018-04-16 00:00:00  2018-04-17 00:00:00
Quantity                        8317.00              6434.00
Total Value (Lacs)            259962.50            230002.50
```

Transpose returned `DataFrame`, set 'Date' column as index:

```
series.groupby(level=0).apply(list).apply(pd.Series).T.set_index('Date')
Out:
                    Quantity Total Value (Lacs)
Date                                           
2018-04-16 00:00:00  8317.00          259962.50
2018-04-17 00:00:00  6434.00          230002.50
```

Apply the solution from **Edit 1**.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but getting error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'` I have edited my question please suggest why I am getting wrong value

Comment: @vishnu hope my explanation will solve your problem. Also if you not sure about data type or method applicability, use `dir()` and `type()` python built-ins to examine your data

Comment: Dear @Mikhail Stepanov, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You are getting this error because the data extracted from the dataframe are strings as shown in your error, you will need to convert the string into a float.

Convert your dataframe to values instead of strings. You can achieve that by:

```
values = df.values
```

Then you can extract the values from this array.

Alternatively, after extracting data from the dataframe convert it to float by using:

```
b=float(df['Quantity'])
```

Comment: Thanks, I have tried something but getting the wrong value. please check edited question

Comment: You're getting the wrong answer because you are doing 259962.5*100000 / 8317*100
this is causing your program to divide first before multiplying, put you multiplications in brackets: (259962.5*100000)/(8317*100)

Comment: So: keep in mind the order of mathematical execution,
    your final code should look like this.. 
df['price'] =  (float(df['Total Value (Lacs)']) * 100000 )/( float(df['Quantity']) * 100)

Comment: Your not helping the community by not choosing the answer that fixed your problem.

Comment: Sorry but I have accepted my answer. I find `Mikhail Stepanov,` answer more useful for me and your answer also helpful but Can I accept two answer ? if possible, I can do that. sorry once again. Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
df['price'] = ((df['Total Value (Lacs)'].apply(pd.to_numeric)) * 100000 / (df['Quantity'].apply(pd.to_numeric)) * 100)
```

Comment: getting error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'`